# Access 2013: Merging the same table-field with different data

Tags: ms-access, merge

I have six tables with identical fields. the group was tasked to input the data with the same fields and I need to merge all into one dataset--- table and form.

Answer (score 0):

create a view likes this:

```
    select * from table1
    union
    select * from table2
    union
    ...
    select * from table6
```